# Which encryption algorithm is used by Watson knowledge studio to encrypt training data

Tags: watson

I would like to know Encryption Algorithm that is used by Watson Knowledge Studio to Encrypt training data. Is it AES256  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To my knowledge, the WKS training data is not encrypted. Could you point me to where you see that it is?

Answer (score 0):

The exported WKS model, that will be used by Watson Explorer, is partially encrypted. But we can not disclose our encryption mechanism.